# Regime Change Stochastic Process

Tags: random, stochastic-calculus

I would like to simulate an Ito process in which the drift and diffusion terms change after hitting a boundary for the first time.

For example, a Geometric Brownian Motion X which has 0 drift and volatility X dZ_t until X reaches some boundary X-hat.  Afterwards, there might be a different drift and volatility.

With my current knowledge of Mathematica, I only know how to simulate the first part, a standard GBM process.  What are the next steps?

It is very possible that I'm using poor terminology due to inexperience, and so any comments or pointers are appreciated.

The code I'm using for the standard GBM is the following:

```
μ = 0;
σ = 0.5;
testfun = ItoProcess[{μ x, σ x}, {x, 1}, {t, 0}];
testdata = RandomFunction[testfun, {0, 1, 0.01}, 5];
ListLinePlot[testdata, AxesLabel -> {t, X[t]}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Simulated Paths", PlotRange -> All]
```

Update: I have tried the proposed answer and found it does not work, as illustrated by my example below:

```
μ = 1;
σ = 0;
start = 0;
fun1 := If[x >= 0.5 || start > 0, start++;  -x, x];
testfun = ItoProcess[{fun1, σ x}, {x, 0.1}, {t, 0}];
testdata = RandomFunction[testfun, {0, 5, 0.01}, 1];
ListLinePlot[testdata]
```

This results in a process that "sticks" at the boundary, rather than one that decays afterwards.  I believe the problem is that the `start` tracker is not working as intended.

Update #2:

I've added a means to simulate multiple paths

```
ClearAll[x, fun1, fun2, ff, gg]
μ = 1;
σ = 0.3;

fun1[x_, t_] :=
 If[t < 0.1, ClearAll[ff, gg]; x,
  If[
   If[
      x < 0.5,
      gg = False; If[ff, gg = True]; False,
      ff = True
      ] && ff || gg, -x, x]
  ]
fun2[x_, t_] := 
 If[If[x < 0.5, gg = False; If[ff, gg = True]; False, ff = True] && 
    ff || gg, σ x, 0]
testfun = ItoProcess[{fun1[x, t], fun2[x, t]}, {x, 0.1}, {t, 0}];
testdata = RandomFunction[testfun, {0, 5, 0.01}, 5];
ListLinePlot[testdata, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Here's a image of the simulated results]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, and 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: Since you "know how to simulate the first part", please include that code (or a simplified version of it) as a starting point to provide context for readers.

Comment: Sure thing.  I used the example in the ItoProcess documentation.  The code has been edited into my original question.

Comment: Done, and thank you to Sjoerd for properly formatting the code.  I realized right after adding that it didn't look right, but he beat me to the edit.

Comment: Is there to be a reversion of parameters if the boundary is re-crossed? In any case, there's no built-in (that I'm aware of) way to "parameterize" the parameters and/or modify them on the fly with some logical construct/test - you'll need to e.g. generate some data, scan it for a crossing, truncate it there, append data with new parameters from that point, rinse-n-repeat...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that this can't be done.The idea is that this is a one-time change of parameter, so that once you cross, you're there forever.  Of course it would become more complicated if you could switch between regimes multiple times.

Comment: perhaps something like: `iproc = ItoProcess[{{If[x[t] <= 2, 0, 1 ] x[
       t]}, {{If[x[t] <= 2, 1, 1/100 ] x[t]}}, x[t]}, {{x}, {1}}, {t, 
    0}];
rf = RandomFunction[iproc, {0., 5., 0.01}];`?

Comment: I believe that gives what I would call a "region change", where the dynamics differ depending on the value of x.  What I'm more interested in is what I call a "regime change" (purely terminology), in which, once a boundary is crossed for the first time, the dynamics are forever changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Second trial.

The following seems to work. The only restriction so far is that it only works on the first path. I will be looking into that.

```
ClearAll[x, fun1, fun2, ff, gg]
μ = 1;
σ = 0.3;

fun1[x_, t_] := 
  If[
    If[x < 0.5, 
       gg = False; If[ff, gg = True]; False, 
       ff = True
    ] && ff || gg, -x, x
  ]
fun2[x_, t_] := 
  If[
    If[x < 0.5, 
       gg = False; If[ff, gg = True]; False, 
       ff = True
    ] && ff || gg, σ x, 0]
testfun = ItoProcess[{fun1[x, t], fun2[x, t]}, {x, 0.1}, {t, 0}];
testdata = RandomFunction[testfun, {0, 5, 0.01}, 1];
ListLinePlot[testdata, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The trick of the baroque Boolean functions is that `If` returns unevaluated if it cannot determine the truth of its condition (and a third argument is missing). We need this because `ItoProcess` evaluates its first argument. Another thing that the above makes use of is that `False && undefined` and `True || undefined` both evaluate (to False and True, respectively).

Comment: Color me surprised if this does what it appears to do, +1 on thought-provoking possibility...

Comment: I have tried a corner case and the `start` tracker does not appear to do the trick.

Comment: @Shffl what was the corner case?

Comment: I've updated my original question.  I suppressed the diffusion component.

Comment: @Shffl see update

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks for suggesting an alternative!

Comment: I've managed to allow it to simulate multiple paths by adding an additional `If` statement in the beginning.  It checks for the first time interval and clears ff (which I renamed to passage) and gg.  This way, I can get multiple paths from RandomFunction.  Code in the updated question.

Comment: I had a test on t==0 that did the same but that didn't work. Your t<0.1 apparently does, but with a time step of 0.01 it means the variables get cleared 10 times. Not really a problem.  You should watch out for situations where the regime change occurs before .1 seconds.